Vertical scroll modifier with child LazyVerticalGrid and LazyColumn Not Working
Putting column with vertical scroll with child lazy vertical Grid gives following error

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Nesting scrollable in the same direction layouts like LazyColumn and Column(Modifier.verticalScroll()) is not allowed. If you want to add a header before the list of items please take a look on LazyColumn component which has a DSL api which allows to first add a header via item() function and then the list of items via items().

I have a ProfileScreen requirement such as Column with verticalScroll inside there there is multiple profile sections such as image and links. The image section have vertical grid of 3 and links section also have vertical grid with max span 2 and span for item varies.
Heres how it is implemented:
Column(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .pullRefresh(pullRefreshState, enabled = true)
        .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())

        .background(mainBackGround)
) {
    //LinksSection()
    Column(
        modifier = modifier
            .padding(padding)
            .shadow(elevation, shape)
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .background(backgroundColor, shape)
    ) {
        LazyVerticalGrid(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(horizontal = 7.dp),
            columns = GridCells.Fixed(2)
        ) {
            items(
                array,
                span = { item ->
                    return@items if (item.thumbnail.orEmpty().equals("small", true)) {
                        if (item.localBig) {
                            GridItemSpan(2)
                        } else {
                            GridItemSpan(1)
                        }
                    } else {
                        GridItemSpan(2)
                    }
                },
            ) {
                gridItems()
            }

            //GallerySection
            Column(
                modifier = modifier
                    .padding(padding)
                    .shadow(elevation, shape)
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .background(backgroundColor, shape)
            ) {
                LazyVerticalGrid(
                    userScrollEnabled = false,
                    columns = GridCells.Fixed(3),
                    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                ) {
                    items() {}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

I have tried with setting fixed height for both but that does not fullfill requirement. Both of these list are scroll disabled for user so they scroll with main scroll, also tried to calculate height for all items but it gives not accurate height as span is changing. This screen is done with xml and works good. If I am converting this to compose, currently stuck with this.
